# using vcpkg+cmake+opencv generate a project, but encounter fatal error: “opencv2/core/core.hpp”: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, cmake, vcpkg

I download OpencV using VCPKG:

```
./vcpkg install opencv2:x64-windows
```

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    opencv2[core,eigen,jpeg,png,tiff]:x64-windows -> 2.4.13.7#5
Package opencv2:x64-windows is already installed

Total elapsed time: 2.225 ms

The package opencv2:x64-windows provides CMake targets:

    find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
    # Note: 15 target(s) were omitted.
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE opencv_ml opencv_ts opencv_gpu opencv_ocl)
```

and write cmakelists like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) 

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE E:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
  CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

# set the project name 
project(QRCODE)
# add the executable 
add_executable(qrcode main.cpp)

find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS REQUIRED)
# Additional Include Directories
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Additional Library Directories
link_directories( ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR} )

# Additional Dependencies
target_link_libraries(qrcode ${OpenCV_LIBS})

message("${OpenCV_DIR}")
message("${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

and what puzzles me is that cmake output looks like this:

```
E:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/opencv
/include/opencv;/include
```

it seems like opencv was not installed successfully, or cmake couldn't find opencv install path.
When I built the project using cmake tool, encountered with fatal error: “opencv2/core/core.hpp”: No such file or directory.

Comment: did you run vcpkg integrate install after installing packages? If so, are you using correct configurations? You should use Debug x64 or Release x64

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. My problem was fixed after I removed the opencv2: x64-windows version and installed opencv: x64-windows, I guess it's the first installation failure which caused the problem.